# Query inside query loop with both query outputs required

Tags: php, mysql, navigation

On my website, I want to make a navigation bar just like [this](https://skyblueguy.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/archive_tree.jpg), with categories (here 2012) and articles (here May - October). I've got a MySQL-database with all categories (infocat_id, name) and one with all articles (title, body, category, infopost_id).

I thought I could code my php as follows:

```
<ul>
   <?php
    $query1 = $db->prepare("SELECT infocat_id, name FROM info_category");
    $query1->execute();
    $query1->bind_result($infocat_id, $name);
    while($query1->fetch()):
   ?>
   <li>
      <?php echo $name; ?>
      <ul>
         <?php
          $query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT title, infopost_id FROM info_posts WHERE category = $infocat_id");
          $query2->execute();
          $query2->bind_result($title, $infopost_id);
          while($query2->fetch()):
         ?>
         <li><?php echo $title; ?></li>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Sadly, that wouldn't work as I got only the first category name and underneath that "Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in [the directory in which the php-file is located] on line [the line which says `$query2->execute();`].

I figured I couldn't use a JOIN, because I also need the output of the first query.

I'm not super experienced with PHP, so if anyone would be able to help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a nested category?

Comment: How you are getting `$infocat_id` that you are using in second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a join, and just check for a change in the key to decide whether to output the title again.

Crudely knocked up and not tested but something like this:-

```
<ul>
   <?php
   $prev_infocat_id = 0;
    $query1 = $db->prepare("SELECT infocat_id, name, title, infopost_id
                FROM info_category
                LEFT OUTER JOIN info_posts
                ON info_category.infocat_id = info_posts.category");
    $query1->execute();
    $query1->bind_result($infocat_id, $name, $title, $infopost_id);
    while($query1->fetch())
    {
        if ($prev_infocat_id == 0)
        {
            echo '<li>';
        }
        else
        {
            if ($prev_infocat_id != $infocat_id)
            {
                echo '</li><li>';
            }
        }
        $prev_infocat_id = $infocat_id;
        echo '<li>'.$title.'</li>';
    } 
    if ($prev_infocat_id != 0)
    {
        echo '</li>';
    }
   ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, your code works great! It only listed the articles, and not the categories, but I got that fixed myself already. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use join to get desired output:

```
 SELECT cat.infocat_id, cat.name,post.title, post.infopost_id  

    FROM info_category cat

    left join 
    info_posts post on post.category=cat.infocat_id
```

Note: Use INNER JOIN if you need data only on matching condition.